# Using Append tool in ArcPy with Edit Session?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, append

I need to run the append tool in an edit session because the feature class I am appending to is in a gdb with a relationship class, and I need to update the field mapping for a few of the fields. I created my Append tool using ModelBuilder to get the "field_mapping" correct.

I created this code and it seems to work okay, however, when I incorporate it into my longer field (with this being the last step) it no longer updates the fields... However, no error seems to occur either.

```
Import arcpy module here
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Script Arguments
Fitting = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Final_Layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Out_Workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

edit = arcpy.da.Editor(Out_Workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, True)

# Process: Append
arcpy.Append_management(Final_Layer, Fitting, "NO_TEST", "ANCILLARYROLE \"AncillaryRole\" true true false 2 Short 0 0 ,First,#;ENABLED \"Enabled\" true true true 2 Short 0 0 ,First,#;EDITEDBY \"Edited By\" true true false 64 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Final_Layer,W_Valve_EDITEDBY,-1,-1;DATEEDITED \"Date Edited\" true true false 8 Date 0 0 ,First,#,Final_Layer,W_Valve_DATEEDITED,-1,-1;PLACEDBY \"Placed By\" true true false 64 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Final_Layer,W_Valve_PLACEDBY,-1,-1;DATEPLACED \"Date Placed\" true true false 8 Date 0 0 ,First,#,Final_Layer,W_Valve_DATEPLACED,-1,-1;LABELTEXT \"Label Text\" true true false 64 Text 0 0 ,First,#;WATERTRACEWEIGHT \"Water Trace Weight\" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#;SYMBOLROTATION \"Symbol Rotation\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;IPID \"IPID\" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,Final_Layer,Count_One_IPID,-1,-1;SUBTYPECD \"Subtype Code\" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,Final_Layer,Count_One_SUBTYPECD,-1,-1;NOMINALSIZE \"Nominal Size\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;MATERIAL \"Material\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#;BRANCHSIZE \"Branch Size\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;DEGREES \"Degrees\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;FRAMME_BASENAME \"FRAMME_BASENAME (FRAMME Tag)\" true true false 20 Text 0 0 ,First,#;FRAMME_IPID \"FRAMME_IPID (FRAMME Tag)\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;FRAMME_RB_PRMRY \"FRAMME_RB_PRMRY (FRAMME Tag)\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;FRAMME_RB_SCNDRY \"FRAMME_RB_SCNDRY (FRAMME Tag)\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;FRAMME_RB_FSC \"FRAMME_RB_FSC (FRAMME Tag)\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;FRAMME_RB_STATE \"FRAMME_RB_STATE (FRAMME Tag)\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;FRAMME_RB_COMPONENT \"FRAMME_RB_COMPONENT (FRAMME Tag)\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;FRAMME_RB_OCCURRENCE \"FRAMME_RB_OCCURRENCE (FRAMME Tag)\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;GPSX \"GPS X Coordinate\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;GPSY \"GPS Y Coordinate\" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#;GPSYESNO \"GPS Yes/ No\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#", "Plug")

edit.stopEditing(True)
```

The only difference between this snippet and my larger script, is that my larger script has different parameters, the "Final_Layer" is actually created in the script rather than being an input... But I don't think that would make much of a difference.

Is there a reason the "editing" session is not kicking in during m larger model?

Or is it related to what I have here?

Comment: What layer are you intending to update the fields?  From you snippet it is 'Fitting'.  Is that correct?

Comment: Have you set merge rules in your field mapping?